# "No such file or directory" when trying to run a file

Tags: cmd

I am running a python file in the directory where the file is and I get 'No such file or directory', with ls -l the file appears with the needed 'x' permission; my command is ./filename.py + options > name of output file

Thank you for your comments. The error resulted because I was using the upper arrow to find a cmd that I used in an earlier version and, even though the recovered cmd read good in the terminal window, the code won't run. By retyping anew the same cmd it worked fine! I think that the corrupted cmd was the result of an ubuntu error (indicated to me by ubuntu) as startup after I put the system to sleep the day before. I think this is the reason because it happened again, and only retyping the cmd anew resolved the problem. Somehow I have problems every time I startup after I put the system to sleep (the corruption of cmd stored by ubuntu do not happen if I startup from a full shut down).

Comment: Can you give us the output of `ls -l`?

Comment: -rwxrwxr-x 1 richardabuli richardabuli    30519  5월 19 22:06 V2_sn .py~
-rwx--x--x 1 richardabuli richardabuli    41871  6월 29 01:32 V2_sn.py
-rwx--x--x 1 richardabuli richardabuli    41867  6월 29 01:09 V2_sn.py~
-rwxrwxr-x 1 richardabuli richardabuli    31639  5월 22 03:11 V3_sn.py~
-rw-rw-r-- 1 richardabuli richardabuli   113411  5월 28 21:39 Vp_G1J50N4.ls

Comment: the file is "V2_sn.py" (it always run  before with the command I mentioned)

Comment: Thanks. Can you edit your question to include those details? In addition, can you also tell us what _exact_ command you tried to run?

Comment: Also, please make sure you have actually `cd`ed to the correct directory before running `./` because `.` stands for "current directory".

Comment: I found the error.  However, I don't know how to edit my question and I submitted the explanation as a comment. The message was that it will be shown after a committee accepts it (maybe in a week). I wish I knew how to edit the damned question! It is my first time asking a question and  I feel stupid. Sorry!

Comment: Click the [edit] link to edit your question :)

Comment: Please post an answer instead of adding the solution you found to your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The error resulted because I was using the upper arrow to find a cmd that I used in an earlier run and, even though the recovered cmd read good in the terminal window, the code won't run. By retyping anew the same cmd it worked fine! I think that the corrupted cmd was the result of an ubuntu error (indicated to me by ubuntu) as startup after I put the system to hivernation the day before. I think this is the reason because it happened again, and only retyping the cmd anew resolved the problem. Somehow I have problems every time I startup after I put the system to sleep (the corruption of cmd stored by ubuntu do not happen if I startup from a full shut down).

Answer (score 0):

Try running it with

```
python filename.py
```

Or

```
python3 filename.py
```

You may need sudo depending on the file.

EDIT: usually the ./ is used for bash scripts

Comment: ./ denotes that the file is in the current directory.  It's used anywhere the path needs to be determined.

Comment: @Stormlord can it be used to execute any scripts? I guess so, as long as it has the #!/bin/bash or something like that

Comment: The command I'm using to run this file always worked before; the ls -l command for this file gives:  -rwx--x--x 1 richardabuli richardabuli    41871  6월 29 01:32 V2_sn.py (I bough the computer in Korea and the date exhibits Korean characters, this is not the problem)

Comment: ./ is just a path determination.  If an executable file, either script or not, is in a different folder than the one you're, you type `/foldername/filename` to run it.  If it's in the current folder, you type `./filename`.  That's all it is.

Comment: yes, this is how I run the file, but somehow it doesn't work anymore

Comment: using the python command gives the same (negative) result: "No such file or directoryy"

Comment: @richardsanchez That means you are not in the directory that contains the Python file you want to run, so you cannot just run with `./`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're running it with `./`, you may need to prepend

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

To your Python file.

If you would like to avoid that, you could just run the file with `python` instead:

```
python script.py
```